# Single Filter tagged with multiple tags in Multi Select Faceting in Solr

Tags: solr

Regarding the Multi Select Faceting, there is a feature whereby we can have a single filter tagged with multiple tags, like the following example:
    fq={!tag=tag1,tag2,tag3}my_field:my_filter

However, I have not been able to figure out the use and advantage of this. Anyone has any information on this? I am using Solr 7.4.0

Edwin

Answer (score 1):

Tagging filters are useful for excluding those filters when faceting. Multi-tagging is useful when certain filters should only apply to specific facets. To expand [the example from the manual](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-TaggingandExcludingFilters):

```
fq={!tag=dt}doctype:pdf&fq={!tag=cat}category:important&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=dt}doctype&facet.field={!ex=cat}category&facet.field={ex=cat,dt}author
```

In this case you can exclude the `doctype` filter for the `doctype` facet, and exclude the `category` filter for the `category` facet, while excluding both when faceting on `author`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From the example and my earlier question, will there be use if I have the following in the fq?
`fq={!tag=dt,cat}doctype:pdf&fq={!tag=dt,cat}category:important`

Comment: Sure, but why would you need to have both tags for both filters? Usually it's more useful to exclude multiple filters in `ex` instead.

Comment: I could not find the usefulness of it too, but I found this in the documentation where it says that a single filter may be tagged with multiple tags, which is why I'm clarifying here. Do you know of any use case which requires this?

Comment: You can have static, hard coded facets for a request handler (set as `invariant` in the configuration) - and then let the code querying decide which facets the filter should be excluded from.